# trouble with IN clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT bm.WinningNumber,bd.BetOnNumber,"WinLossAmount" = 
      CASE            
         WHEN 2 in (2,1) THEN ('WIN')
               END    
FROM BettingMaster bm inner join BettingDetail bd on bm.GameID = bd.GameID
where bd.GameID = 1
```

This works as a Charm and I get 'WIN' in WinLossAmount. Now I actually have value 2 in column WinningNumber(varchar) and value 2,1 in column BetOnNumber(varchar). I retried the statement as

```
SELECT bm.WinningNumber,bd.BetOnNumber,"WinLossAmount" = 
      CASE            
         WHEN bm.WinningNumber in (bd.BetOnNumber) THEN ('WIN')
               END    
FROM BettingMaster bm inner join BettingDetail bd on bm.GameID = bd.GameID
where bd.GameID = 1
```

This doesn't work. Is it not possible this way?! Any help??

Comment: bm.WinningNumber in (bd.BetOnNumber) is equivalent (example) with 2 in ('2,1') which is always false

Comment: try t0 write '2' in ('2,1'), you will not get any result

Comment: A slight side note - if you find yourself putting comma separated values into a column in a database table, your design is probably wrong.  These should probably be in a separate BetOnNumbers table, linked to your BettingMaster table ID (this would make this query simpler, and probably save you time in the longer term).

Comment: '2' in ('2,1') doesn't work as well

Comment: Thanks Paddy, yeah really makes sense and I agree but i've a scenario where this needs to be done

Comment: What database are you using? If it's MySQL, you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to match against a comma-separated list.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but I am using MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN operator in SQL searches values in the row set. But in the second example you try to find INT value in the STRING so you can't use `IN` this way.

In the most SQL systems you can try to use following condition. Where `+` is a concatenate operator in MSSQL (in Oracle `||`, in MySQL `CONCAT()`)

```
WHEN ','+bd.BetOnNumber+',' LIKE '%,'+CAST(bm.WinningNumber AS VARCHAR(10))+',%' 
     THEN ...
```

Also in MySQL you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
WHEN FIND_IN_SET(bm.WinningNumber,bd.BetOnNumber) THEN ...
```

PS: Both ways can't use indexes so you shouldn't use them on big tables.

Comment: Thanks Valex, it worked..Just copy pasted it thinking why am i doing this :) ..Guess have to look through my whole design again. But thanks a ton again!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that in the first statement, SQL is comparing 2 to 1 and then 2 to 2, all integers. Obviously, finding the match and working.

In the second case, you're comparing 2 to a string of "1,2" and 2 does not equal "1,2". You'll need to split the varchar into a series of integers before you compare it. Take a look at:

[Parse comma-separated string to make IN List of strings in the Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause)

This should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use IN and then specify a column name, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT  bm.WinningNumber ,
        bd.BetOnNumber ,
        "WinLossAmount" = CASE WHEN bm.WinningNumber IN (
                                    SELECT  bd.BetOnNumber
                                    FROM    BettingMaster bm
                                            INNER JOIN BettingDetail bd ON bm.GameID = bd.GameID
                                    WHERE   bd.GameID = 1 ) THEN ( 'WIN' )
                          END
FROM    BettingMaster bm
        INNER JOIN BettingDetail bd ON bm.GameID = bd.GameID
WHERE   bd.GameID = 1
```

Comment: Tried it, not doing!!