# Stored-procedure or SQL-query to find recipes, which related ingredients list contains whole passed list of strings

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I'm using .net, mssql, LinqToSQL. My mssql db has the following schema - Recipes are related to Ingredients. Now I want to let users to find recipes by several ingredients.
I need a stored-procedure or query which I can use to select all those recipes.
The number of searching ingredients is unknown.

I tried to use lintosql

```
var list = datacontext.Recipes.Where(r => values.All(v => r.RecipeIngredientMeasures.Any(i => i.Ingredient.NameTrans == v))).ToList();
```

Where values is array of my searching ingredients.

But then I got

> "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: Have you tried replacing the usages of `Any` with `Contains` in your query?

Comment: How will that look like?
...r.RecipeIngredientMeasures.Contains(...) - this Contains is waiting for RecipeIngredientMeasure entity, not for boolen expression.

Comment: First do something like `var ingredientNames = i.Ingredient.Select(x=>x.NameTrans)` then do the contains on that.

Comment: for each recipe? loop over 1.000.000 recipes for each search? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the SQL query I use to use for this case.

```
declare @ingredNames table (name nvarchar(255));

-- so you need to split the list of ingredient comma separated string to table
-- to do that take a look to the link in the comments
insert into @ingredNames (name) values ('rice'), ('chicken');

-- get recipes that have all the specified ingredients
select r.Id, r.Name as number from Recipies as r 
inner join RecipeIngredientMeasures as rim on rim.RecipeId= r.Id
inner join Ingredients as ing on rim.IngId= ing.Id

inner join @ingredNames as ingN on ingN.name = ing.NameTrans 
Group By r.Id, r.Name
Having count(ing.Id) = (select count(name) from @ingredNames )
```

good luck.

Comment: missed link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause

Comment: Glad to help :) ,wouldn't you mark it as an answer please.