# SQL Server: user defined function parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sqldatatypes

I was wondering if it is possible to create a user-defined function that can take a parameter of varying length (as well as other parameters).

Essentially I want to pass a parameter that then gets used in an `IN` statement. What I would like to do is have something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnGetOpenNotificationValue 
    (@LegacyTypeID INT, 
     @MonthEnd DATE, 
     @YearStart DATE, 
     @YearEnd DATE)
```

Where `@LegacyTypeID` is a list of integers.

So then using the function might look something like this

```
SELECT RE_Auxiliary.dbo.ufnGetOpenNotificationValue
    ((1,2,3),'2014-07-31','2013-09-01','2014-08-31')
```

rather than

```
SELECT RE_Auxiliary.dbo.ufnGetOpenNotificationValue
        (1,'2014-07-31','2013-09-01','2014-08-31') + 
    RE_Auxiliary.dbo.ufnGetOpenNotificationValue
        (2,'2014-07-31','2013-09-01','2014-08-31') + 
    RE_Auxiliary.dbo.ufnGetOpenNotificationValue
        (3,'2014-07-31','2013-09-01','2014-08-31')
```

but if I try and pass multiple integers I get an error stating

```
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

Comment: *Table Valued Parameters* are about as close as you can get E.g. [Pass table as parameter into sql server UDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf) - You cannot pass variadic arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Alex K. - I think I'd stick to calling the function 3 times and summing them, if the list was longer I might have considered the table method you proposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex K states you can't pass arrays as an input for a SQL function. You can pass table types ([Pass table as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf)).

```
CREATE TYPE TableType 
AS TABLE (LegacyTypeID INT)

CREATE FUNCTION ufnGetOpenNotificationValue 
(@LegacyTypeID TableType, 
 @MonthEnd DATE, 
 @YearStart DATE, 
 @YearEnd DATE)
...
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT LegacyType FROM @LegacyTypeID)
```

You would then need to insert into a TableType variable before calling your function with that variable passed as a parameter

Another option would be to pass in your list in as a comma separated list of values. And then use a function ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause)) to use in your where clause

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnGetOpenNotificationValue 
(@LegacyTypeID NVARCHAR(256), 
 @MonthEnd DATE, 
 @YearStart DATE, 
 @YearEnd DATE)
...
WHERE COLUMN_NAME in (SELECT val FROM dbo.f_split(@StringParameter, ','))
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
SELECT RE_Auxiliary.dbo.ufnGetOpenNotificationValue
('1,2,3','2014-07-31','2013-09-01','2014-08-31')
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Fletcher, creating another function to split a comma seperated list seems like an elegent solution and not as awkward as creating the Table Valued Parameters that Alex K recommended