# SSRS 2008 - How keep the SAME order enter in the parameter to be reflected in the report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS 2008 Report that when entering a list of ITEM numbers in a multiple data type parameter will return the Item Number, UPC, Description, and Item Status.

It works. 
But my problem is that it sorts my data in my report. Example.
If I enter the following Item Numbers in the parameter:
ZZZ
DDD
AAA
HHH

My report shows the Data alphabetic as:
AAA
DDD
HHH
ZZZ

I want my data to be displayed in the order of the ITEM Number how I enter them.

I have One Data Set:
SELECT ItemNo, UPC, Description, Status
  FROM Product
    WHERE ItemNo IN (@ITEM)

I have One Parameter: 
@ITEM
   Datatype: Text
   Allow multiple values

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string into a table and then set an order to the table you've created.  Then you have something to sort by.

First - create a function that you can call in your sp. (the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause) question gives you exactly what you need)

then, in your query you can use the function just like a table.

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @x = 'ZZZ DDD AAA HHH'

SELECT * FROM f_split(@x,' ') param
WHERE param.seq > 1
ORDER BY param.val
```