I have a question regarding the MSSQL WHERE IN clause
I would like to take one argument value from MSSQL, separate the data based on , (comma), put it in the where clause, and search it. The number of ,(comma) is random.
If I need to use a variable by declaring it, I need to dynamically create a variable according to the number of ,(commas). Is there a way to do this?
The query of the procedure I created is as follows. That query does not work.
@IN_ORDER_NO VARCHAR(100)


DECLARE @SPLIT NVARCHAR(200)

SET @SPLIT = TRIM(CHAR(39)+REPLACE(@IN_ORDER_NO, ',', CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39))+CHAR(39))

SELECT *
FROM EX_TABLE
WHERE EX_COLUMN IN (@SPLIT)

Please tell me how.
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(39)+REPLACE('11111111,202408050001', ',', CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39))+CHAR(39))

If you put the result from here into the query below, you will get a value, but if you run it as a procedure, no result will come out.
Could it be a single quote problem?
CHAR(39) is the '(single quote) code
SELECT *
FROM EX_TABLE
WHERE EX_COLUMN IN (@SPLIT)


Microsoft's SQL Server is not the same thing as MySQL or Oracle. Why all the tags? Please choose only the one that you're actually using.

You've tagged a lot of different DB systems here.  Depending on the one that you're using (and the version thereof) the approach that you would take to dealing with this requirement may be different.  Please update your tags to most accurately reflect the product (and version) that you are using

Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

I didn't know this because it was my first question. I edited the tag. Thank you for your advice.

Unfortunate that a diamond moderator approved this staging ground post without addressing such issues

Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause

This question is similar to: Parse comma-separated string to make IN List of strings in the Where clause. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In your posted WHERE EX_COLUMN IN (@SPLIT) condition, the @SPLIT variable is just a simple string no different than any other string. Since it is a single value, the expression is equivalent to WHERE EX_COLUMN = @SPLIT. SQL server semantics have no provision for further parsing that string into a list of strings just because it is referenced by an IN (...) operator.
What you can do is:

Generate a complete dynamic SQL statement and execute it using EXEC.
Perform substring matching as shown in the other answer.
Use the STRING_SPLIT() function to convert the comma-separated list into a collection of values that can be referenced in an IN (subselect) operation or a JOIN.

The latter option avoids the inefficiencies of pattern matching and produces a query that is SARGable, meaning it can make efficient use of indexes.
SELECT *
FROM EX_TABLE
WHERE EX_COLUMN IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IN_ORDER_NO, ','));

SELECT X.*
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IN_ORDER_NO, ',') S
JOIN EX_TABLE X
  ON X.EX_COLUMN = S.value;

If EX_COLUMN is a numeric or UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type, data type precedence will force a conversion of the S.value string to match that type before performing the lookup or comparison. (If you prefer, you can add an explicit conversion using CAST(), CONVERT(), TRY_CAST(), or TRY_CONVERT() to the S.value reference.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo of the various oprions.

Given that you are on SQL Server, which does not have the broadest of string functions, you could go with this LIKE trick:
SET @INP = '11111111,202408050001'

SELECT *
FROM EX_TABLE
WHERE ',' + @INP + ',' LIKE '%,' + EX_COLUMN + ',%';


Why LIKE as opposed to STRING_SPLIT?

@MatBailie I rather like my version :-P

@TimBiegeleisen Why do you put a comma after where?

@mongvely - The extra delimiters on both sides of the LIKE expression are needed to avoid partial string matches like '23' matching '123,789'.
